# Divide by Subquery returning 'Subquery returned more than 1 value.' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, division

I have the following table in which I have two sales orders and each sales order has a different number of transactions.

| SaleOrder | Transaction | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | T1 | 20 |
| S1 | T2 | 20 |
| S2 | T1 | 15 |
| S2 | T2 | 15 |
| S2 | T3 | 15 |

The problem is I am getting the total sales order amount against each transaction in SQL Server table when in fact they need to be divided equally among the number of transactions like this:

| SaleOrder | Transaction | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | T1 | 10 |
| S1 | T2 | 10 |
| S2 | T1 | 5 |
| S2 | T2 | 5 |
| S2 | T3 | 5 |

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT SalesOrder,
     Transaction,
     Max(Amount) / (SELECT COUNT(Transaction) AS Transaction FROM Test_Table GROUP BY SalesOrder)
    FROM Test_Table
    GROUP BY SalesOrder,
        Transaction
```

But it is giving me 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows `=, !=, <, <=, >, >=` or when the subquery is used as an expression.' error. Can someone explain what this is and how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `group by`, just window functions:

```
SELECT SalesOrder, Transaction,
       Amount) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY salesorder)
FROM Test_Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in the subquery you `GROUP BY SalesOrder` it returns 1 row for each `SalesOrder`.
But you want the number of transactions for the specific `SalesOrder`.
Use MAX() and COUNT() window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrder, Transaction, 
       MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrder, Transaction) / 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrder)
FROM Test_Table
```

If the data type of the column `Amount` is INTEGER then SQL Server will perform integer division, so maybe you need to multiply first by `1.0` so that you get a correct result with decimal places:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrder, Transaction, 
       1.0 * MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrder, Transaction) / 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrder)
FROM Test_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT SaleOrder, [Transaction]
    , Max(Amount) / COUNT([Transaction]) over (partition by SaleOrder)
FROM Test_Table GROUP BY SaleOrder,[Transaction]
```