# SQL Query Challenge. Divide by Subquery returning 'Subquery returned more than 1 value.' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, business-intelligence

I have the following table in which I have two sales orders and each sales order has a different number of transactions.

| SaleOrder | Transaction | Amount | Tax | Delivery Charge | TotalTax (Including Tax of Delivery Charge) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | T1 | 12 | 0 | 3 | 5.5 (This also includes Tax in Column 4) |
| S1 | T2 | 27 | 4 | 3 | 5.5 |
| S2 | T1 | 15 | 2.5 | 5 | 6 |
| S2 | T2 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 6 |

In each SaleOrder, I've a different number of transactions and each transaction has different invoice amount in amount column plus tax of each transaction in tax column.

In sale order 1, I had a delivery charge of 6 which I divided by the number of transactions and got 3 against each. Similar is the case with sale order 2 where total delivery charge was 10.

Now in TotalTax column, I am getting the sum of tax of delivery charge and transaction repetitively.

How can I create a column in SQL Server with separate delivery charge tax, like this:

| SaleOrder | Transaction | Amount | Tax | Delivery Charge | TotalTax | Delivery Charge Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | T1 | 12 | 0 | 3 | 5.5 | 0.75 |
| S1 | T2 | 27 | 4 | 3 | 5.5 | 0.75 |
| S2 | T1 | 15 | 2.5 | 5 | 7 | 1.25 |
| S2 | T2 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 1.25 |

Consider SaleOrder 1, where tax of transactions (0 + 4) and tax of delivery (1.5) equals 5.5 and it is posting against each transaction. I don't have the need for TotalTax column but I need to separate 1.5 from it and divide against each transaction resulting in 0.75.

Similarly in SaleOrder 2, where tax of transactions (2 + 2.5) and tax of delivery (2.5) equals 7 and it is posting against each transaction. I need to separate 2.5 from it and divide against each transaction resulting in 1.75.

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what you tried so far. What was the query that generated the error.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the database engine you are actually using. And most likely the same solutions proposed for your [very similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441405/divide-by-subquery-returning-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value-error) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subtract the total of the tax column from the `total_tax` and then divide by the number of transactions.  That uses window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (total_tax - sum(tax) over (partition by SaleOrder)) * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by SaleOrder) as DeliveryChargeTax
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27d925bef96fb62ac6f5c29ad39e9cad) is a db<>fiddle.